# Orleans cluster communication

Tags: orleans

I am trying to figure out how much of a perf-hit will be if hosting 2 different Orleans grains in the same cluster vs deploying the 2 different grains in different clusters within the same Virtual Network.  Can someone give some guidance on this and also how will the 2 grains can talk to each other in this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently out of the box Orleans only supports direct grain to grain communication within the same cluster. If you have 2 different clusters (2 different Azure Deployments) you need to add a layer of front ends and call via front ends. For example, grain a in cluster A will make an HTTP call to a front end in cluster B which will forward to grain b in his cluster B.

We are currently in the process of adding support for multi clustering in Orleans, which will also include geo-distributed clusters (different data centers). You can find a lot of details here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/948
Some ongoing works is: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/milestones/Multi-Cluster